# Why won't the div tags align to the centre?

Tags: html, css

```
.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4 {
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    display : inline-block;
    border: 3px white solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align : center;
}
```

The code for the question is in: https://jsfiddle.net/cfr9su45/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.b1,
.b2,
.b3,
.b4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.b1 {
  background: red;
}

.b2 {
  background: blue;
}

.b3 {
  background: salmon;
}

.b4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b1"> </div>
<div class="b2"> </div>
<br/>
<div class="b3"> </div>
<div class="b4"> </div>
```

The `text-align: center` for the isn't aligning the `div`'s to the centre. Why? And what is the code to make it align to the centre (without any space from the top, just the centre)

I don't want to try:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I just want those 4 div's to be in the centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.b1,.b2,.b3,.b4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.b1 {
  background: red;
}

.b2 {
  background: blue;
}

.b3 {
  background: salmon;
}

.b4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'center'>
  <div class = "b1"> </div>
  <div class = "b2"> </div> <br/>
  <div class = "b3"> </div>
  <div class = "b4"> </div>
</div>
```

You can create another container , `div` and use `text-align : center;` Because [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) property applies to block containers.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `text-align: center` is a property that needs to go on the container of the items you want to center.

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cfr9su45/1/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4 {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  display : inline-block;
  border: 3px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align : center;
}

.b1 {
  background: red;
}

.b2 {
  background: blue;
 
}

.b3 {
  background: salmon;
}

.b4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "b1"> </div>
     <div class = "b2"> </div> <br/>
    <div class = "b3"> </div>
    <div class = "b4"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Following up on the comment by @deathjack2-0 and @marco-luzzara, if you want to properly do it, you need to re-structure your code. Currently you do not have a container on your `div` items.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "b1"> </div>
    <div class = "b2"> </div> <br/>
    <div class = "b3"> </div>
    <div class = "b4"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Applying properties to the body isn't a good idea unless it's a background color or something. Add a container around your divs.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "theContainer">
      <div class = "b1"> </div>
      <div class = "b2"> </div> <br/>
      <div class = "b3"> </div>
      <div class = "b4"> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And apply the CSS property to that instead.

```
.theContainer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cfr9su45/4/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.theContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4 {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  display : inline-block;
  border: 3px white solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.b1 {
  background: red;
}

.b2 {
  background: blue;
 
}

.b3 {
  background: salmon;
}

.b4 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "theContainer">
      <div class = "b1"> </div>
      <div class = "b2"> </div> <br/>
      <div class = "b3"> </div>
      <div class = "b4"> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then why don't you create a div that encapsulate your 4 divs? So you use `text-align` on the new div.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara I just finished editing my question. I didn't do it because I followed the structure of the OP's code that was posted on JSFiddle.

Comment: Cool. Works well. Thank you.

Comment: @Ricky Dam I know, actually my answer was for the comment that Maccen Wright posted :)

Comment: @MaccenWright Glad I could help out! Don't forget to accept an answer to your question and help out the community! Keep on coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `text-align: center;`property needs to go to their parent, in your case, the body.

Comment: Create a parent div for them then.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want a `text-align:center;` you can set margin but it's not very clean :

```
.b1,.b3
{
  margin-left:calc(50% - 108px);
}
```